# How to get findAll() method to work on a Iterable object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Im trying to write a method in the service layer which returns a list of Objects so i can pass it to my API Controller. My findAll() method gives me the error: Incompatible types found: Iterable. Required: List. So I thought using a Set instead of a List but it gives me: Cannot infer arguments (unable to resolve constructor).

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong here and why my student object is being seen as a Iterable. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My code looks as following:

**ServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

    //Incompatible types found: Iterable. Required: List
    public List<Student> findAll() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    //Cannot infer arguments (unable to resolve constructor)
    public Set<Student> getStudents()
    {
        Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>(studentRepository.findAll());
        return students;
    }

    public ArrayList<Student> getStudentsList(){
        return (ArrayList<Student>) this.studentRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public interface StudentService {

    List<Student> findAll();
    Set<Student> getStudents();
    ArrayList<Student> getStudentsList()


}
```

**API Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/students")

public class StudentAPIController {

    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

    public StudentAPIController(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    //cannot resolve .getStudentsList
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> findAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(StudentServiceImpl.getStudentsList);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> findAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(StudentServiceImpl.findAll());
    }
}
```

**Normal StudentController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/s")
public class StudentController {

    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

    public StudentController(StudentRepository studentRepository){
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView list(){
        Iterable<Student> students = this.studentRepository.findAll();
        return new ModelAndView("students/list" , "students", students);
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public ModelAndView view(@PathVariable("id") Student student) {
        return new ModelAndView("students/view", "student", student);
    }
}
```

**StudentRepository**

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {

}
```

Comment: Did not understand your issue, ypu get compilation error ? What is the StudentService code ? In JpaRepository : List<T> findAll(); is the definition

Comment: I have added my Service and Repository code. I am making use of a CrudRepository instead of JpaRepository, so maybe my problem may be laying there?

Answer (score 0):

In the JPA or Dao layer use like this

```
public List<T> findAll() {
            return entityManager.createQuery("your query").getResultList();
    }
```